# When I uncomment a line of code I get [500] internal server error?

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I cannot figure out what could be causing this error. My Apache log is not recording any errors in the access log or error log regarding the page, yet somehow whenever I uncomment the `header()` line I get a 500 Internal Server Error. It can't be coming from PHP's fatal error when content is outputted before `header()` is called, that wouldn't cause a 500 would it?

```
header("Location: /offices/page-".ceil($cache->size() / 15));
```

I tested `$cache->size()` and it's returning 22, so it should append a 2 to the end of the string and redirect. I did have `ob_start()` called before the `header()` but I tried calling `ob_end_clean()` right before it and it still did nothing...

I even tried putting `header("Location: /offices");` at the very beginning of the file and it still gives me a 500.

Comment: reason might be - you need to remove space after location :

header("location :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script continues to execute after your header() call. You need put `exit;` immediately after it. This shouldn't cause a 500 error, though.

Edit: Evidently this worked - meaning your problem is probably in some related code further down the page?

Comment: If uncommenting header() was the only other change and this fixed it then *weird*.

Answer (score 8):

Another reason might be - you need to remove **space** after `location` :

`header("location :`
   `header("location:`

If that's not your problem, then try to check the php & apache **error logs**.

Comment: that was literally hidden from my eyesight. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a fully formed URL:

```
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/offices/page-".ceil($cache->size() / 15));
```

Comment: I tried putting in `header("Location: http://www.example.com");` still 500 error.

Comment: @animuson Ok, that's weird. :)

Comment: Whoever it was that said put `exit` immediately after it, seems to have worked. I put `exit` right after the `header` call and it's redirecting just fine now...

Comment: Were you possibly outputting any other headers after this one?

Comment: No, the original `header` call that I was using was fairly near the end of the script execution. It would not have been possible for another `header` call to be sent that late in the script. All, if any, of them are sent right at the beginning of script execution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing going on.  After repeatedly banging my head on the monitor, it isn't the header("Location: myPage.php"); line that is broken - it is myPage.php that is broken!  Try redirecting to another page.  I hope I save someone else time

Answer (score 1):

I literally had the same problem,but it seems that I wrote header("Location : page.php")instead of header("Location: page.php");. YES that one space makes a difference!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the culprit was a pesky *extra comma* in the function's arguments.
It worked fine locally but not when deployed. Here it was:

```
function myFunction ($a,$b,$c, <- this comma){
 foreach(etc) {
   ...
   return header($x);
};
```

Comment: Consider upgrading your PHP version. All supported versions allow a trailing comma

Comment: You're correct, the server was on PHP 7.2.24. I still don't know why my answer was considered not useful, when it does in fact suggest a fix for a similar scenario.